# case class Rails extends Scala with Drupal (exists: Boolean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drupal, scala

I like aspects of Scala, Rails, and Drupal, and would be interested in Scrupal

Scala because it's strongly typed, concise, fast, both functional & OO, and massively scalable (not to mention being the [TBD] successor to Java)

Rails because it brings together a number of sensible conventions under one roof that make web development creative and enjoyable. In a bare nutshell, MVC + Routing + ORM + Validation + REST (much more obviously, including Ruby, but in terms of the essential components)

Drupal for providing a flexible drag & drop interface that unifies content management and content display.

---

Now, having just read Odersky et al Programming in Scala, and discovering the [ScalaQuery](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ScalaQuery&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://scalaquery.org/&ei=a6zWTv9jiNOyBs2JwdEO&usg=AFQjCNErpPHMNCzuQtuUD31gbBd_ls1_xw) ORM (a JVM LINQ) and its totally [SIQ](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ScalaQuery%20SIQ&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQxQEwAA&url=http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3akigRD8FpWj8J%3ahttps://wiki.scala-lang.org/download/attachments/1310722/Scala-Integrated-Query-Scala-Days.pdf%2bScalaQuery%2bSIQ&hl=en&gl=fr&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgWEC3pE4KpRrA06NEBPnnpxKYHwinqOjYo5UgseD2n_9Mg7xIKZG79TOfigj-m50kWJh2Y_849EiUt4Hhleq3Vqu4xrYp_Qdhf3sT3ukEEdFvw69GhB7yYvKorOq0DtANpaen9&sig=AHIEtbS7QeyleqTP4LD9OcMCfCrN1G9ryg&ei=EazWTv7jLIXMtAaP6fGiDg&usg=AFQjCNEx7S095VW8wCwy-t62SNWOyCDDHg) future with [TypeSafe](http://typesafe.com/stack), the language and ORM components of Scrupal are taken care of (why not .NET/C#/LINQ? Valid point. I prefer Linux and Mono is always a step behind and/or restricted by what they can replicate in terms of M$ latest & greatest)

As for Scala Rails (Scails), [Scalatra](http://www.scalatra.org/) provides routing, REST and the V(iew) with [Scalate](http://scalate.fusesource.org/), but is missing the MC as well as the ORM. Love the lightweight simplicity but Scalatra is Sinatra, not Rails. [Play 2.0 Scala](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaHome) version is apparently Rails inspired, but running through the documentation does not bring a sigh of relief by any means, particularly the non-ORM, ANORM. For the time being maybe Play 2.0 is the only viable Scala Rails option, will have to dig a little deeper, wish it was more DRY and concise like Scala itself.

So, assuming Scala Rails already exists, the missing link is Scala Drupal, arguably the hardest part given that it does not exist ;-) Perhaps it's a pipe dream combining Drupal's data driven Content Management Framework (CMF) with a compiled language like Scala.  Are the two mutually exclusive or is it possible to create a performant data driven Scrupal? If so, how do you envision the full stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

play is actually very neat and by the way it does not tie you to Anorm, I have used hibernate/JPA and Sienna both of which work pretty fine. it would be interesting to note what you found missing in the framework :-)

implementing something like Drupal is very possible in whatever stack you would choose! I would say go with the TypeSafe stack.

Comment: play 2.0 is a bit less DRY than one would like, take a look at the google group and some of the change requests. Yes, anorm is out and ScalaQuery is in ;-) I did say that play 2.0 is Scala Rails, at present there is no other (yes, Grails of course, but not Scala driven). TypeSafe stack is looking quite impressive, agreed that will certainly be the foundation on which Scrupal is built. I should point out that it is not necessarily Drupal that I want, but a comprehensive drag & drop interface for dynamically managing content within a compiled application.

Comment: drag & drop - check out jquery ui. its more of front end than server side :) play 2.0 is still in an early view stage - i am sure by the time its rolled out, it would have addressed most of the concerns raised :-) you could use plan 1.x until then ;-)

Comment: The be all-end-all stack does not yet exist, although pairing a strongly typed language such as Scala with Rails conventions and Drupal GUI features would be a serious nice-to-have. For the time being Play 2.0 Scala version achieves the Scails aspect; as for Scrupal, TBD

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://liftweb.net/ ? It covers REST, ORM, Validation, you can use MVC, but the more common method is [view first](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/View_First). It also bring great comet/ajax support, security you don't have to worry about and a [few other things](http://seventhings.liftweb.net/)

Comment: Yes, I checked out Lift, albeit briefly. I am unsure about the future of Lift: it's noteworthy that TypeSafe publicly announced Play as joining their stack, tough news for Lift-ees I imagine, a slap in the face even.  At any rate, I'm a big fan of the Rails approach to web development, so Play 2.0 Scala appears to be the clear choice for Scrupal development at this point. I should look at Lift more in-depth, it does shake the easy tree of tried-and-true convention, and obviously has merit, otherwise it would not have the following that it does...

Comment: While Lift doesn't have TypeSafe's support, there are several companies that offer commercial support for Lift, if that is something you need. And then you have the Lift community, which is very strong and always available on the mailing list. Anyways, best luck on your project!